When I start my PC then GRUB 2.12 is showing. How can I fix it?
When I start my PC then GRUB 2.12 is showing. How can I fix it ?

GNU GRUB version 2.12

What are you wanting to show...  Grub can modified to not show, but this can be problematic if you make a mistake in the future & thus need to use grub to enabling booting  (which is why its commonly shown by default; even with a short timer).  What are you trying to do, as a bootloader showing is usually a good thing maintenance wise.

Why have you asked this question multiple times?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511615/why-this-grub-2-12-is-showing-and-how-to-fix-it

Does this answer your question? How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up at the beginning of boot?
